# WPF TreeView filter item in HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I implemented simple example where `TreeView` filtered with `CollectionViewSource`. But how to search in nested nodes? How to implement filtering in nested nodes?

For example if in `textbox` will Be `France`it will seek in nested note and return France.

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding SearchPattern, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <I:Interaction.Triggers>
                <I:EventTrigger EventName="TextChanged">
                    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}" ></command:EventToCommand>
                </I:EventTrigger>
            </I:Interaction.Triggers>
        </TextBox>
        <TreeView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding YourFilteredCollection}" >
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
        <Button Grid.Row="2">Start</Button>
    </Grid>
```

**FooViewModel.cs**

```
public class FooViewModel
    {
        FooModel model = new FooModel();

        private string searchPattern = string.Empty;

        public string SearchPattern
        {
            get
            {
                return searchPattern;
            }

            set
            {
                searchPattern = value;
            }
        }

        private bool UserFilter(object item)
        {
            return (item as Node).Name.Contains(SearchPattern);
        }

        public ICollectionView YourFilteredCollection
        {
            get
            {
                var source = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(model.Items);
                source.Filter = UserFilter;
                return source;
            }
        }

        public ICommand TextChangedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new RelayCommand(() => YourFilteredCollection.Refresh());
            }
        }
    }
```

FooModel.cs

```
 public class Node
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
    }

    public class FooModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Node> Items { get; set; }

        Random rnd = new Random();

        public FooModel()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Node>
        {
            new Node
            {
                Name ="Europe",
                Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>
                {
                    new Node {Name="Germany" },
                    new Node {Name="France" },
                    new Node
                    {
                        Name ="Great Britain",
                        Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>
                        {
                            new Node {Name="England" },
                            new Node {Name="Scotland" },
                            new Node {Name="Wales" },
                            new Node {Name="North Ireland" },
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            new Node
            {
                Name ="Asia",
                Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>
                {
                    new Node {Name="China" },
                    new Node {Name="Japan" },
                    new Node { Name ="India" }
                }
            },
            new Node { Name="Afrika" },
            new Node { Name="USA" },
            new Node { Name="Australia" }
        };
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [recursion](https://introprogramming.info/english-intro-csharp-book/read-online/chapter-10-recursion/), something that can call itself to get to the many levels deep of a tree view.  Something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Node>> FindCollection(ObservableCollection<Node> collection, ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Node>> retVal){
    foreach ( Nodes node in collection){
        if (node.Nodes.Count > 0){
            collectionToCheck = node.Nodes;
            FindCollection(collectionToCheck,retVal);
        }
        if ( node.Name == SearchPattern ){
            retval.Add(collection);
            break;
        }
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

You call the routine to get the collection that the name belongs to, then you can bind it to a gridview, or do anything else you need with it.

```
public void ApplyFilter(){
    ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Node>> collection = FindCollection(Items,new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<Node>());

    foreach(ObservableCollection<Node> nodeCollection in collection){
         //...iterate over the node collection that contained the filtered item
    }
}
```

There are many ways to implement recursion, I'm not saying this is the best, but it is an example of how I needed it with one of my programs, and at least provides an example to help get you to the right place.  Take the code at face value, I tried to incorporate how I implemented it using your example.  You may need to tweak it for your circumstance.